# How to convert BST to vector, and why is my code not working?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree

```
vector<int> *bstValuesToVector(BinaryTreeNode *root) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    vector<int> *v;

    vector<int> *leftAns = bstValuesToVector(root->left);
    vector<int> *rightAns = bstValuesToVector(root->right);

    if (leftAns != nullptr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftAns->size(); i++) {
            v->push_back(leftAns->at(i));
        }
    }

    v->push_back(root->data);

    if (rightAns != nullptr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rightAns->size(); i++) {
            v->push_back(rightAns->at(i));
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

It is not giving any error on compiling, but it is also not successfully returning something, what can be the problem ?

Comment: Where do you think you're creating a vector for `v` to point to? (Why the abundance of pointers? If you had actually created any vectors, you would have so many memory leaks...)

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a container, so just use it.

```
struct BinaryTreeNode {
    BinaryTreeNode* left;
    BinaryTreeNode* right;
    int data;
};

std::vector<int> bstValuesToVector(BinaryTreeNode *root) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return {};
    }

    std::vector<int> v;

    std::vector<int> leftAns = bstValuesToVector(root->left);
    std::vector<int> rightAns = bstValuesToVector(root->right);

    // for (int i = 0; i < leftAns.size(); i++) {
    //     v.push_back(leftAns[i]);
    // }
    for (auto data : leftAns) {
        v.push_back(data);
    }

    v.push_back(root->data);

    // for (int i = 0; i < rightAns.size(); i++) {
    //     v.push_back(rightAns[i]);
    // }
    for (auto data : rightAns) {
        v.push_back(data);
    }

    return v;
}
```

---

Copying a `std::vector` is usually very expensive, you could take a lesson of [Inorder Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal) at first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to access the memory of a not allocated pointer that first occurs here : `v->push_back(root->data);`.

1. You need to actually create a vector and keep its address into your "v" pointer as follows :

   `vector<int> *v = new vector<int>();`

If you do this, then you need to avoid the memory leak by releasing your partial result vectors :

```
if (leftAns != nullptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < leftAns->size(); i++) {
        v->push_back(leftAns->at(i));
    }


    delete leftAns;  // see this line
}
```

Analog for `rightAns`

2. Stop naming your variables as "v", "Ans", use the best naming you can! See [why](https://www.freshconsulting.com/insights/blog/development-principle-1-choose-appropriate-variable-names/).

My suggestion as @zjyhjqs written:

```
struct BinaryTreeNode {
    BinaryTreeNode* left;
    BinaryTreeNode* right;
    int data;
};

std::vector<int> bstValuesToVector(BinaryTreeNode *root) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return {};
    }

    std::vector<int> result;

    std::vector<int> leftData = bstValuesToVector(root->left);
    std::vector<int> rightData = bstValuesToVector(root->right);

    for (auto data : leftData) {
        result.push_back(data);
    }

    result.push_back(root->data);

    for (auto data : rightData) {
        result.push_back(data);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between if (leftAns != nullptr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftAns->size(); i++) {
            v->push_back(leftAns->at(i));
        }
    }         and.    for (auto data : leftData) {
        result.push_back(data);
    }   and.   Thanks for vector<int>*=new vector<int>, it worked

Comment: The difference is that for accessing an intem of the vector I’m using the iterator of vector in : ‘for(auto data : leftData)’ instead of using the index of the vector as in: ‘for(int i = 0; i<……)’. In my example I’m not using pointer, i do use directly the object since anyway i’ll allocate a new object and using of pointer is not improving my speed/memory anyway.